# Jenkins Ansible EC2 dynamic inventory does not work

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

### UPDATE

Don't remember how I fix it but seems like it is just because of permission is wrong on the ec2.py script.

---

I have some `Ansible` playbooks to deploy on `AWS EC2` with dynamic inventory setting.

It works fine when using `ansible-playbook` inside the server

```
ansible-playbook setup.yml
```

It is on `Ubuntu 14.04` and `Ansible` `2.0.1.0` with default `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

```
[defaults]
remote_user = ubuntu
hostfile = /etc/ansible/ec2.py
host_key_checking = False
```

I got the `ec2.py` and `ec2.ini`  http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html

When triggering the playbook on `Jenkins` using this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ansible+Plugin

It returns error about the `ec2.py` since it thinks hostfile is `ini` file

```
ERROR! The file /etc/ansible/hosts is marked as executable, but failed to execute correctly. If this is not supposed to be an executable script, correct this with `chmod -x /etc/ansible/hosts`.
Inventory script (/etc/ansible/hosts) had an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/ansible/hosts", line 1328, in <module>
    Ec2Inventory()
  File "/etc/ansible/hosts", line 177, in __init__
    self.do_api_calls_update_cache()
  File "/etc/ansible/hosts", line 424, in do_api_calls_update_cache
    self.get_instances_by_region(region)
  File "/etc/ansible/hosts", line 469, in get_instances_by_region
    conn = self.connect(region)
  File "/etc/ansible/hosts", line 440, in connect
    conn = self.connect_to_aws(ec2, region)
  File "/etc/ansible/hosts", line 458, in connect_to_aws
    conn = module.connect_to_region(region, **connect_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/__init__.py", line 66, in connect_to_region
    return region.connect(**kw_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/regioninfo.py", line 187, in connect
    return self.connection_cls(region=self, **kw_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 103, in __init__
    profile_name=profile_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1100, in __init__
    provider=provider)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 569, in __init__
    host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/auth.py", line 989, in get_auth_handler
    'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check your credentials

/etc/ansible/hosts:3: Error parsing host definition ''''': No closing quotation
```

If I use the option `Inline content` with `Dynamic inventory` then it use a random `.ini` file like this

```
/usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook /data/ansible-playbooks/setup.yml -i /tmp/inventory487543089183487870.ini -f 5
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
```

Has anyone got this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the inventory can not load the `ENV`. The error above means can not load the credentials. I update the `~/.aws/credentials` with IAM credential then the playbook works fine now.